# ERROR in Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive MatPrefixRejector

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is Angular Project Version 4 and Angular cli 1.2.6, and I am getting this error when I build in production mode:

```
ERROR in Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive MatPrefixRejector in C:\TestProject/app/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/index.d.ts.

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\TestProject\app\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

I have tried to delete the `node_modules` and reinstall it, and I have also checked other possible solutions, but it did not work.